# Using Selenium (Python) to click "download" button and download PDF from Chrome

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to download the collection of PDF files (in zip) from a website. I managed to get the browser open and click on the correct button, however, download doesn't happen.

I've tried changing default directory, adding more options and etc but nothing seems to be working.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option('prefs',  {
    "download.default_directory": r"USING FULL PATH HERE\\",
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True
    }
)
service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

driver.get('https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/international-journal-of-greenhouse-gas-control/vol/127/suppl/C')

# Find the button using XPath
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div/main/section[1]/div/div/div/form/button/span')

# Click on the button
button.click()

time.sleep(5)

driver.quit()
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the working code below:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/international-journal-of-greenhouse-gas-control/vol/127/suppl/C')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Download full issue']")))

# Click on the button
button.click()
driver.quit()
```

Note: I changed your XPath expression to be more user readable and less flaky.

### UPDATE:


**Root cause:** The website identifies the bot(your automation script) and won't allow to download, this is the root cause.

**Solution:** To overcome this issue, you need to use a third party library known as `undetected_chromedriver`. This library ensures website won't recognise the bot. So you need to install `undetected_chromedriver` first.

Then use the below working code which uses `undetected_chromedriver`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

driver = uc.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/international-journal-of-greenhouse-gas-control/vol/127/suppl/C')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
# Click on download button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Download full issue']"))).click()
# Close the pop-up window
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//span[@class='button-text'])[5]"))).click()
```

Comment: Thanks, Shawn! Somehow this doesn't work for me. The code runs, but still no download in the folder.

Comment: @aveyilagrun - Ok I understand the root cause now. Please check the updated answer and try the solution. Let me know if it works.

Comment: thank you, still no download though. At this point, I am convinced something is wrong with my machine or IDE.

Comment: Are you sure installed `undetected_chromedriver ` successfully? Also which version of selenium are you using? When you run the code from my answer, does it open your default browser, or it open a new profile browser?

Comment: yes undetected_chromedriver is downloaded successfully. Selenium version: 4.10.0. It opens a new profile browser when running your code.

Comment: That's the issue, it should open the default profile. Can you try using Selenium `v4.9.0`?There seems to be some issue with selenium `v4.10.0` and `undetected_chromedriver`

Comment: just tried using selenium 4.9.0 but nothing changed. it still pops up as a new browser.

Comment: You need to figure that issue out first. Then am pretty sure, it will download successfully.

Comment: managed to get the thing working! So I changed the version to 4.9.0 & instead of waiting until clickable to close the pop up window i just did time.sleep(10). Thank you for your help! :) `# Click on download button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div/main/section[1]/div/div/div/form/button/span'))).click()
time.sleep(10)
driver.quit()`

Answer (score 0):

After clicking the button to initiate the download, you need to wait for the file to be downloaded before quitting the browser.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Click on the button
button.click()

# Wait for the file to be downloaded
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'html')))

driver.quit()
```

Added some import of additional modules WebDriverWait and expected_conditions from selenium.webdriver.support.ui and selenium.webdriver.support respectively. These modules allow you to wait until a specific condition is met. In this case, we wait until an HTML element is present, which indicates that the download is complete.
Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! But there is still no download present in the folder :(

Comment: how does it manually happen. Can you try to distinguish between those like manually and via automation with params like time taken to download or one click works or any other prompt comes in between. If it times out then try to increase the timeout and give it a try after that.

Comment: usually you just press on "download full issue" button and then you get a notification window that pdfs are being downloaded as a zip file & then you usually get a window to store the download somewhere; and it happens pretty fast as well, so i am not sure if increasing timeout will help